# Android static fragment: When layout height is wrap_content then text don't show properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, fragment

When trying to use static fragment with `layout_height="wrap_content"`  UI doesn't appear as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1”
                android:name=“…..”
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/fragment2" />
    <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2”
                android:name=“….”
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment2 has layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview”
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1”
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn”2
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When try to reload content in WebView with text

```
web.loadData("I confirmed that I have read and understand all the materialfasd<br>fasd<br>fase<br>....fasd", "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

It appear something like this in device

[image]

Any solution how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment 2

**Replace**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
```

**With**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
```